# Collective term for the nationality of a person and country of incorporation of a company

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm trying to find a term that would be equally suitable to describe the nationality of a person, as well as to describe the country of incorporation of a company, I'm ready to give up and use the nationality for the organization, or maybe there is another option?

Comment: Our Help Center specifically states that questions about "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" are off-topic here.

Comment: Ok, let's remove the phrase "for a database field" from the question, this will not change the essence of my question.

Comment: @Cascabel: Might be a bit personal, but could you please share some of your favourite books on/about _words_? :)

Comment: Not sure if I understand...do you mean apart from a dictionary or thesaurus? I also have a firefox plug-in for synonyms.

Comment: I can only think of "locality" but if you want someone to provide those details, be specific so they know exactly what you mean.

Comment: Great, your version is now my working version, thanks  If there are no other options, will use it.

Comment: ...suppose I am an Australian living in Canada I would not reply with my nationality,  so you should be specific as to what is meant.

Comment: @Cascabel: Any book/s on or about _words of the English language_, _word etymologies_, _stories behind them_, and so forth.

Comment: How about the word "nation" for my case, which is sometimes used as synonym for country?

Comment: See [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/), [PhraseFinder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/),

Comment: “I am ready to refuse” - typo?

Comment: Most likely "I'm ready to give up" 

Comment: If what is wanted is the country of incorporation, then you should say 'the county of incorporation'. Using for a corporation some vague term that is also suitable for a natural person is asking for trouble, because the country of incorporation may be different from the country where the headquarters are located, which in turn may be different from the country where most of its business operations are conducted, etc.

Comment: In the context in which I'll use this collective term, there will be no problem with this, so I still intend to find it.

Comment: Thank you, @Cascabel!